# Friendly URL of Get method in RAZOR views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, razor, query-string

Hi i have a page in razor that sorts an information, every time i need to make some change to my search i have to pass values by QueryString, i have many reasons to do that.

now my url looks like this:

```
https://localhost:44300/Reports/TitleSearch/SearchDirectTarade/DirectTradeExclusive?Input.SelectedMarket=DirectTradeExclusive&Input.SelectedProduct=131&Input.SelectedIssuer=&Input.SelectedOperation=C&Input.SelectedSubjacentGroup=&Input.SelectedSubjacent=US0028962076&Input.SelectedStrike=#
```

and i want to make it look like this:

```
https://localhost:44300/Reports/TitleSearch/SearchDirectTarade/DirectTradeExclusive
```

i also need to pass all those parameters by query string, so
there is any possibility to make my URL more user friendly in MVC4 Razor pages?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Url.Action('MyAction', 'MyController', 
    new { Input.SelectedMarket = DirectTradeExclusive, 
          Input.SelectedProduct = 13 } )
```

Comment: can you explain your solution please?

Answer (score 0):

If, like you said, "every time i need to make some change to my search i have to pass values by QueryString" then you have no other option but to pass them in the QueryString.

If you did not want to have the parameters in the URL, you could use a POST when you change the search or you could also set them in a cookie or session.

Comment: my app doesn't use cookies nor session, i have everything on DataBase, my problem appeared when i change my form on page from [POST] to [GET]. I have some javascript on a page that make [GET] to my controller and it´s does´n pass formcollection by [GET], so i have to pass values used in javascript [GET] by QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

The main question here is why do you want to make this url user friendly?
If your main goal is to allow user to send/store this link to similate same request later, then you are already solved your problem. In other case, if you, for instanse, want to let user to remember short url, then you have to either reduce the number of search parameters, or hash your search url (like bit.ly does).
Basically, I can think about a few solutions:
if you don't need repetative searches by url:

- hide query parameters in POSTed values
- hide query parameters in cookies or httpheaders (be careful, some firewals filters unknown headers)

if you want search to be repetative:

- move query parameters to url path (you may mark them as optional in routing)
- (My favourite) Leave as is, or maybe just to shorten query parameters' names

Basically, if you don't have limited number of searched options and don't have to have landing pages for them (screw you SEO), it's a common practive to GET your search results and put search parameters in query string (Google is a most notable example)

Answer (score 0):

you can change URL logic or patteren & defaults values in App_Start/Route_Config file

Default patteren could be changed.